# tkMessageBox dialog icon is duplicated in unpredictable ways

Tags: python, tkinter, tkmessagebox

Consider:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkMessageBox
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

if True:
    tkMessageBox.askyesno("aa", "bb?")
tkMessageBox.askyesno("aa1", "bb1?")
tkMessageBox.askyesno("aa2", "bb2?")
```

[image]

When the second or the third (the results vary between the runs!) `tkMessageBox.askyesno` is invoked, two icons (both for the title "aa1" or "aa2", respectively) appear on my Ubuntu 16.04 launcher as shown in the above screenshot. I tried doing `root.update()` between the calls of `tkMessageBox.askyesno` without improvement. What is going on and how do I fix this?

Comment: one is for the root window, one is for the popup window.

Comment: @BryanOakley The root window is withdrawn.

Comment: Sure, but some window managers will still create an icon for it. That seems to be what is happening here.

Comment: I recommend you try to not pop up the dialogs immediately, but wait until after `mainloop` starts running (eg: you can put them in a function, and call the function with `after_idle`).

Comment: @BryanOakley There is no icon for `root` if I do not invoke the dialog. Also, the title of that icon suggests that it refers to the dialog. Furthermore, in the real script, more than two `tkMessageBox.askyesno` dialogs are invoked one after another and I get more than two icons. I do not use the main loop of `tkinter`, since I am using `pyinotify`, which has its own main loop. Any other workaround?